How to include a div-based widget in a web form
I am creating a webform, and would like to allow the user to select time ranges to indicate availability for scheduling appointments. I found this widget:
Week-Multirange-Elessar
that works great. The problem is that the widget itself is a div, not a form element so the info doesn't get included if a form gets submitted. The included demo uses javascript to simply print the ranges to the page which is cool. But how do I include the availability info in an actual webform to be submitted with the other contact information from the form?
Do I use javascript to submit the form, and somehow include the availability data? Why would the author not make this a form widget?

You could use a hidden input on your form and then set the value of that input to the selected datetime using javascript once the datetime has been selected.
Add the hidden input:
<form>
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="appointment_time">
</form>

And then where the widget author uses JS to print the time to the page, modify that to set the value of your hidden input to the time:
$("#generateObj").on("click", function(ev) {
  ...
  console.log(week);
  document.querySelector('input[name="appointment_time"]').value = week;
});

And then just submit your form as normal.
